# Solving for a variable

Tags: trigonometry

Assuming that we're given the function:

$$I_r(n) = \cos^{n-1}(\dfrac{45°}{n-1})$$

Which models the remaining intensity of a wave of light. n is how many polarizers must be placed (i.e. more polarizers means more intensity passes through)

If I want at least 95% of the intensity to remain, I've figured out through brute force that n must be 7.

My question is: Is there a way to solve for n for the following equation?

$$\cos^{n-1}(\dfrac{45°}{n-1}) = 0.95$$

I've messed around with it a bit, but I'm just not seeing an easy way.

Comment: I'm confused as to why $I_r(1)$ does not exist, but I suppose that's a separate issue.  I don't see an elegant solution to it, especially when this seems like an elementary physics question which might demand a brute-force solution.

Comment: Yeah, there's a restriction where n must be at least 2. Should've mentioned that. I half-expected it to simply be a brute-force question, but I wanted to see if anyone else might've seen something I didn't.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not seeing it with elegant eyes.  Someone else may very well come along and blow your mind. Is there a Wikipedia article that might elucidate something random and nifty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions to these kinds of equations typically don't have a nice formulas; you have to use numerical approximation methods.

For example, if you solve for the $n$ in the cosine you get:

$$
n = 1+ \frac{\pi/4}{\cos^{-1}(0.95^{1/(n-1)})}
$$

If you iterate this formula starting with $n = 2$, after a few iterations you end up with $n = 7.030050255876$ which is pretty close.

Comment: I know this is old, but thank you for the help. You're right. That is how I had to solve it.